# Intuition and Visualization of Limits of Complex Rational Functions

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, rational-functions

I am having some difficulty evaluating and visualizing limits of complex rational functions. For example, $$ \lim_{z \to z_0 } f(z),\ where\ Im(z_0)\ne 0,\ Re(z_0)\ne 0$$
$$f(z):=\frac{L(z)}{M(z)}, where 
\ M(z)\ne 0$$

I know that the general epsilon-delta definition of a limit is akin to its counterpart in real analysis, but I admit that I am having some difficulty trying to use it to evaluate limits of complex rational functions when $z_0$ has non-zero real and imaginary parts.

$$\forall \epsilon_{>0} \exists \delta_{>0} \ |f(z)-L|<\epsilon\ whenever\ 0<|z-z_0|<\delta$$

Would it help to mentally re-formalize the above epsilon-delta definition as follows to make the definition more concise?

$$\forall \epsilon_{>0}\  \exists \delta_{>0} |Re(f(z))-Re(L)|<Re(\epsilon)\ whenever\ 0<|Re(z)-Re(z_0)|<Re(\delta);$$
$$\forall \epsilon_{>0}\  \exists \delta_{>0} |Im(f(z))-Im(L)|<Im(\epsilon)\ whenever\ 0<|Im(z)-Im(z_0)|<Im(\delta);$$

Comment: Us the fact that $|M(z)| \geq |M(z_0)|-|M(z)-M(z_0)|>|M(z_0)|/2$ when $|z-z_0|$ is small. Do not go to real and imaginary parts.

Answer (score 1):

You should be thinking about discs, not intervals: $f(z)$ tends to $L$ at $z_0$ iff for any positive radius $\epsilon$, there is a positive radius $\delta$, such that for all $z$ in the disc of radius $\delta$ around $z_0$, $f(z)$ is in the disc of radius $\epsilon$ around $L$. This means that $f(z)$ tends to $L$ as $z$ tends to $z_0$ from any direction with a rate of convergence that is within a constant factor of the rate of convergence from any other direction.